# Responsive Web design Layout Code

Tags: html, responsive-design, dreamweaver

```
*
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    background-color: #FFAF0A;
    }

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
}

#header {
    background-color: #222222;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
}

#body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}

#leftNav {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
#content {
    width: 85%;
    float: right;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: white;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #222222;

    height: 100px;
}
```

Hello all, this is my layout for my web page. Is this responsive? If not how can I make it responsive. When it comes to graphics what do i do with pixels? convert them to percentages?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would remove like almost all of the height: numbernumberpx; lines... maybe except for like like footer and header and left nav.. well, its up to you... Responsive means that your website will look good on any size screen... so just drag and shorten your browser to see how it looks on smaller screens

Answer (score 1):

'Responsiveness' has more things to consider than making heights and widths in % of the total available. It should include css `@media` queries, should consider resized images for different screen widths, should also consider image layouts and dimensions for device positions like ipad vertical or horizontal.

This 'responsive' term is still not clearly defined and I can say the stylesheet you wrote above is **not responsive.**

**EDIT**

Since you are doing this in dreamweaver, it has all things you need to do for a responsive web scroll. Just follow to create responsive web page while starting a new project. Also, dreamweaver has really good interface in the bottom of the editor which has tabs of desktop, mobile device, and a tabular device icons which show how your code looks in each type of device. You should also have flexibility of jquery-mobile in it, because it contains all those things bundled, and more interestingly, it writes plain CSS for your wysiwyg editing. (*Though it includes many stylesheets, beyond you feel their requirement*).

Comment: It's flexible (cause of the `%`) but not responsive (lack of `@media`)

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you so much! I know nothing about @media, i'm new to web design, so would you recommend to just make a fix website 1000px in width? centered?

Comment: Thank you for your edit, I forgot to mention that I'm suppose to make a website only using html and css, no java, media, PHP, etc. Thank you for your input though, you have been great help with your first answer. 
I shouldn't even be using dream weaver due to the software generated code, but there is no way of anyone finding out so it should be okay.

Thanks again!

Comment: 960 px is what most of the world's computers today have the maximum screen width. So if you want to be obedient to your users, consider that width. since you are new to web design, I would recommend you to start learning some css framework like [this one](http://960.gs/).

Comment: sivatumma, thank you for your comment. I will not use 1000px, i will use 960px. 
http://www.computing.northampton.ac.uk/~13422770/index.html
This is what I've managed to create, only using css.

Thank you for the link, i will book mark it and try and learn when I'm finished with my school work.

Most appreciated again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use css3 @media queries to include or exclude items depending on the size of you page.

A good way to experiment would be to shrink or expand your browser on a desktop of laptop computer.

For more on this, see..

[Css Media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

The others are correct about % though. When you use declare % rather that static px dimensions, you are setting your elements to adapt to a certain % of their parent elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my assignment dictates me to use CSS and HTML only, thank you. I shall forget about % and stick to pixels.

Comment: % is part of plain css. you should in fact, consider its use.

Answer (score 0):

Still your css will behave like liquid layout. It will break on very large screen. As you wish to create the website on 960px. So you have to give the css for wrapper like below:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    max-width:100%;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

due to `max-width:100%` your wrapper will automatically behave liquid format in small screens. Other child elements you can use % value as well.

Now there is a question how to convert fix px value to % or em.

So here is the simple rule to do this.

**for em value:** *child width / parent width = em*

**For % value:** *(child width / parent width)x100 = %*

Example:

```
#wrapper width is: 960px;
#leftNav width is: 200px;
#content width is: 750px;
```

Now for per you have to do follow the above mention rule:

```
#leftNav {
    float: left;
    width: 20.83333333333333%; /* (200/960)x100 */
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

#content {
    width: 78.125%; /* (750/960)x100 */
    float: right;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

you can use this rule to define the fonts size in percent or em .